# How to get F# version number?

Tags: f#

I know that VS 2010 has F# 2.0 and VS 2012 - F# 3.0.
But how I can get F# version number, for example in F# interactive? Is there some command, for example: 
`#ver;;`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you start up F# Interactive window in VS, you get something like:

```
Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 2.0.5.0
Copyright (c) 2002-2010 Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> [Loading init.fsx]
>
```

which includes everything you need.

To open F# interactive window one can press : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

**Update (5/16/2018):**

Information format seems to have changed a bit in VS 2017. Language version comes in the end :

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.1.0 for F# 4.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't paid attention to it before. But can I get build number programmaticlly?

Comment: Because I see that F# is changing from version to version and I want to be sure that I use right code.

Comment: @Alex: AFAIK, F# doesn't expose `fsi` version in its API.

Comment: you can use reflection. Load FSharp.Core assembly a check the version. Assembly version of F# 3.0 is 4.3.0.0.

Comment: F# Interactive in Visual Studio 2013 displays `Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.21005.1` on startup, so F# version is no longer included.

Comment: @PaulJurczak It is back in VS 2017 and seems all is good now. The information format has changed a bit though. It says - `Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.1.0 for F# 4.1`.

Comment: I'm using F# in Mac, when running `fsharpi` you get the same message in your terminal with the version.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same question as well.

The best I can get on windows is:

```
dotnet fsi --version
```

Result is

> Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 12.0.1.0 for F# 6.0

It is supposed to have a "fsc.exe" file on windows. But I can not find it.

Answer (score 2):

It's written in Windows' control panel's programs and features.

Comment: Only if it was installed. If it was simply unzipped somewhere, it won't be. Also, multiple versions may be installed, so the list of installed programs wouldn't help disambiguate which one was running.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst https://stackoverflow.com/a/10985973's solution is good, I prefer somthing I can put into a build script.

As such, I use a dummy F# project and build it using msbuild.
 - This will show the fsc.exe command line path.

Taking that path, I then run it without any arguments and it will show the version.

There doesn't seem to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

In MacOs/Linux you use `fsharpi` which is a wrapper over `fsi` used in Windows, so from a terminal you can get the version in the same way as @pad already pointed out:

```
>fsharpi

Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 10.2.3 for F# 4.5
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

>
```